# Getting Error while using Custom Data Generator in Tensorflow to Train U-Net Model using custom coco dataset

Tags: tensorflow, imagedatagenerator, pycocotools

When I try to train the U-net model with a custom data generator function I get an error from tensorflow.
I tried changing the shapes etc and troubleshooted a lot.There is some logical error i guess, please help solving this issue

Data Generator Function

```
def dataGeneratorCoco(images, classes, coco, folder, 
                      input_image_size=(224,224), batch_size=4, mode='train', mask_type='binary'):
    
    img_folder = '{}/{}-data/images'.format(folder,mode)
    dataset_size = len(images)
    catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=classes)
    
    
    c = 0
    while(True):
        img = np.zeros((batch_size, input_image_size[0], input_image_size[1], 3)).astype('float')
        mask = np.zeros((batch_size, input_image_size[0], input_image_size[1], 1)).astype('float')

        for i in range(c, c+batch_size): #initially from 0 to batch_size, when c = 0
            imageObj = images[i]
            
            ### Retrieve Image ###
            train_img = getImage(imageObj, img_folder, input_image_size)
                        
            ### Create Mask ###
            if mask_type=="binary":
                train_mask = getBinaryMask(imageObj, coco, catIds, input_image_size)
            
            elif mask_type=="normal":
                train_mask = getNormalMask(imageObj, classes, coco, catIds, input_image_size)                
            
            # Add to respective batch sized arrays
            # print(img.shape,train_img.shape)
            img[i-c] = train_img
            mask[i-c] = train_mask
            
        c+=batch_size
        if(c + batch_size >= dataset_size):
            c=0
            random.shuffle(images)
        yield img, mask
```

Data Augmentation Generator

```
def augmentationsGenerator(gen, augGeneratorArgs, seed=None):
    # Initialize the image data generator with args provided
    image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(**augGeneratorArgs)
    
    # Remove the brightness argument for the mask. Spatial arguments similar to image.
    augGeneratorArgs_mask = augGeneratorArgs.copy()
    _ = augGeneratorArgs_mask.pop('brightness_range', None)
    # Initialize the mask data generator with modified args
    mask_gen = ImageDataGenerator(**augGeneratorArgs_mask)
    
    np.random.seed(seed if seed is not None else np.random.choice(range(9999)))
    

    while(True):
        for img, mask in gen:
            seed = np.random.choice(range(9999))
            # keep the seeds syncronized otherwise the augmentation of the images 
            # will end up different from the augmentation of the masks
            g_x = image_gen.flow(255*img, 
                                 batch_size = img.shape[0], 
                                 seed = seed, 
                                 shuffle=True)
            g_y = mask_gen.flow(mask, 
                                 batch_size = mask.shape[0], 
                                 seed = seed, 
                                 shuffle=True)

            img_aug = next(g_x)/255.0
            mask_aug = next(g_y)

            yield img_aug, mask_aug
```

But when I try training the model i get the corresponding error

```
UnknownError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  Exception: input type is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1030, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 831, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_284939/3839959985.py", line 15, in augmentationsGenerator
    for img, mask in gen:

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_284939/728327123.py", line 25, in dataGeneratorCoco
    train_mask = getNormalMask(imageObj, classes, coco, catIds, input_image_size)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_284939/2567587607.py", line 29, in getNormalMask
    new_mask = cv2.resize(coco.annToMask(anns[a])*pixel_value, input_image_size)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycocotools/coco.py", line 442, in annToMask
    rle = self.annToRLE(ann)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycocotools/coco.py", line 427, in annToRLE
    rles = maskUtils.frPyObjects(segm, h, w)

  File "pycocotools/_mask.pyx", line 308, in pycocotools._mask.frPyObjects

Exception: input type is not supported.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[Shape/_10]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  Exception: input type is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1030, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 831, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_284939/3839959985.py", line 15, in augmentationsGenerator
    for img, mask in gen:

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_284939/728327123.py", line 25, in dataGeneratorCoco
    train_mask = getNormalMask(imageObj, classes, coco, catIds, input_image_size)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_284939/2567587607.py", line 29, in getNormalMask
    new_mask = cv2.resize(coco.annToMask(anns[a])*pixel_value, input_image_size)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycocotools/coco.py", line 442, in annToMask
    rle = self.annToRLE(ann)

  File "/home/navneeth/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycocotools/coco.py", line 427, in annToRLE
    rles = maskUtils.frPyObjects(segm, h, w)

  File "pycocotools/_mask.pyx", line 308, in pycocotools._mask.frPyObjects

Exception: input type is not supported.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_3047]

Please Help Me


I tried multiple ways for solving could not get through please help me in getting this done.
```

Comment: I would guess that the type of `anns[a]` you are passing to `coco.annToMask` is not correct. You could try to check that ...

Comment: Tried changing that two, still not working